# Cloudinary Image Uploads Not Persisting Other Form Data in Prisma PostgreSQL Database with Next.js TypeScript

Tags: typescript, postgresql, next.js, axios, prisma

I'm working on a web project using Next.js with TypeScript, and I've hit a roadblock with integrating Cloudinary for image uploads alongside Prisma for data storage in a PostgreSQL database.

I've followed a tutorial by JavaScript Mastery on YouTube, where the instructor used Grafbase for their server setup. However, I've already set up my project to use PostgreSQL with Prisma and Axios.

The problem I'm encountering is that while I've successfully set up Cloudinary for image uploads, only the images are being uploaded to Cloudinary. The rest of the form data, such as titles, URLs, categories, and descriptions, is not being submitted to my database via Prisma.

I've thoroughly reviewed my form component, API route handler, and Prisma model, but I'm still unable to identify the root cause of the problem. It seems like there might be a misconfiguration or oversight in my code, but I'm struggling to pinpoint it.

Could someone please provide me with detailed guidance on properly integrating Cloudinary image uploads with Prisma PostgreSQL database in my Next.js TypeScript project?

actions.ts

```
import { ProjectForm } from "@/common.types";
import { Client } from "@clerk/nextjs/server";
import axios from "axios";

const API_BASE_URL = "/postCreate";
export const uploadImage = async (imagePath: string) => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch("/api/upload", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({ path: imagePath }),
    });

    return response.json();
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
};
export const createNewProject = async (form: ProjectForm) => {

  try {
    const imageUrl = await uploadImage(form.image);
    if (!imageUrl.url) {
      throw new Error("Image upload failed");
    }

    const response = await axios.post(API_BASE_URL, {
      ...form,
      image: imageUrl.url,
    });

    return response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
};
```

post_data.ts

```
import { ProjectForm } from "@/common.types";
import prismadb from "../../../lib/prismadb";
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
import cloudinary from "cloudinary";
export default async function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse
) {
  if (req.method === "POST") {
    try {
      const formData: ProjectForm = req.body;

      const newPost = await prismadb.posts.create({
        data: {
          title: formData.title,
          description: formData.description,
          imageUrl: formData.image,
          liveSiteUrl: formData.liveSiteUrl,
          category: formData.category,
          subCategory: formData.subCategory,
        },
      });
      res.status(200).json(newPost);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error creating post:", error);
      res.status(500).json({ error: "Failed to create post" });
    }
  } else {
    res.status(405).end();
  }
}
```

common.types.ts

```
export interface ProjectForm {
    title: string;
    description: string;
    image: string;
    liveSiteUrl: string;
    category: string;
    subCategory: string;
  }
```

route.ts

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { v2 as cloudinary } from "cloudinary";

cloudinary.config({
  cloud_name: process.env.CLOUDINARY_NAME,
  api_key: process.env.CLOUDINARY_KEY,
  api_secret: process.env.CLOUDINARY_SECRET,
});

export async function POST(request: Request) {
  const { path } = await request.json();

  if (!path) {
    return NextResponse.json(
      { message: "Image Path Is Required!" },
      { status: 400 }
    );
  }

  try {
    const options = {
      use_filename: true,
      unique_filename: false,
      overwrite: true,
    };

    const result = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(path, options);

    return NextResponse.json(result, { status: 200 });
  } catch (error) {
    return NextResponse.json({ message: error }, { status: 500 });
  }
}
```

project_form.tsx

```
"use client";

import Image from "next/image";
import { ChangeEvent, useState } from "react";
import { FormField } from "./ui/form";
import Formfield from "./Formfield";
import { Button } from "./ui/button";
import {
  backendLanguages,
  categoryFilters,
  frontendLanguages,
  subCategory,
} from "@/lib/data";
import {
  CustomBackendMenu,
  CustomFrontendMenu,
  CustomMenu,
  CustomSubMenu,
} from "./customMenu";
import toast from "react-hot-toast";
import { createNewProject } from "@/lib/actions";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";

type Props = {
  type: string;
};

const projectForm = ({ type }: Props) => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const handleFormSubmit = async (e: React.FormEvent) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    setIsSubmitting(true);

    try {
      if (type === "create") {
        await createNewProject(formData);
        router.push("/");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      return toast.error("ERROR!");
    } finally {
      setIsSubmitting(false);
    }
  };

  //ORIGINAL FUNCTION
  const handleChangeImage = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const file = e.target.files?.[0];
    if (!file) return;

    if (!file.type.includes("image")) {
      return toast.error("Please upload an image file.");
    }

    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);

    reader.onload = () => {
      const result = reader.result as string;
      handleStateChange("image", result);
    };
  };

  //ORIGINAL FUNCTION
  const handleStateChange = (fieldName: string, value: string) => {
    setFormData((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [fieldName]: value,
    }));
  };

  const [isSubmitting, setIsSubmitting] = useState(false);
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    title: "",
    description: "",
    image: "",
    liveSiteUrl: "",
    category: "",
    subCategory: "",
  });


  return (
    <form
      onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}
      className="flex items-center justify-start flex-col w-full lg:pt-24 pt-12 gap-10 text-lg max-w-5xl mx-auto"
    >
      <div className="flex items-center justify-start w-full lg:min-h-[400px] min-h-[200px] relative">
        <label
          htmlFor="poster"
          className="flex justify-center items-center z-10 text-center w-full h-full p-20  text-gray-800 border-4 border-black/80 border-dashed"
        >
          {!formData.image && "Choose a image for your poster"}
        </label>
        <input
          id="image"
          type="file"
          accept="image/*"
          required={type === "create"}
          className="absolute z-30 w-full opacity-0 h-full cursor-pointer"
          onChange={handleChangeImage}
        />
        {formData.image && (
          <Image
            src={formData?.image}
            className="sm:p-10 z-20"
            alt="Post Image"
            layout="fill"
            objectFit="contain"
          />
        )}
      </div>
      <Formfield
        title="Title"
        state={formData.title}
        placeholder="COMPIL"
        setState={(value) => handleStateChange("title", value)}
      />
      <Formfield
        title="Description"
        state={formData.description}
        placeholder="Description about the resource."
        setState={(value) => handleStateChange("description", value)}
      />
      <Formfield
        type="url"
        title="Website URL"
        state={formData.liveSiteUrl}
        placeholder="https://www.compil.com"
        setState={(value) => handleStateChange("liveSiteUrl", value)}
      />

      <CustomMenu
        title="Category"
        state={formData.category}
        filters={categoryFilters}
        setState={(value) => handleStateChange("category", value || "")}
      />

      <CustomSubMenu
        title="SubCategory"
        state={formData.subCategory}
        filters={subCategory}
        setState={(value) => handleStateChange("subcategory", value || "")}
      />
      <div className="flex items-center justify-start w-full">
        <Button
          type="submit"
          variant={"default"}
          className="w-full text-lg"
          disabled={isSubmitting}
        >
          {isSubmitting
            ? `${type === "create" ? "Creating" : "Editing"}`
            : `${type === "create" ? "Create" : "Edit"}`}
        </Button>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};

export default projectForm;
```

Upon submitting the form, I expected all form data, including image files and other fields such as titles, URLs, categories, and descriptions, to be uploaded to Cloudinary and persisted in my PostgreSQL database via Prisma.

Here's what actually happened: While the image files were successfully uploaded to Cloudinary, the other form data was not being submitted to my database via Prisma. Only the image URLs were stored, while the rest of the form data remained missing from the database.